# Dynamic programming approach to calculating Stirling's Number

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, non-recursive

```
int s_dynamic(int n,int k) {
    int maxj = n-k;

    int *arr = new int[maxj+1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= maxj; ++i)
        arr[i] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= k; ++i)
        for(int j = 1; j <= maxj; ++j)
            arr[j] += i*arr[j-1];

    return arr[maxj];
}
```

Here's my attempt at determining Stirling numbers using Dynamic Programming.

It is defined as follows:

> S(n,k) = S(n-1,k-1) + k S(n-1,k), if 1 < k < n
>
> S(n,k) = 1, if k=1 ou k=n

Seems ok, right? Except when I run my unit test...

```
partitioningTest ..\src\Test.cpp:44 3025 == s_dynamic(9,3) expected:    3025    but was:    4414
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

BTW, here's the recursive solution:

```
int s_recursive(int n,int k) {
    if (k == 1 || k == n)
        return 1;

    return s_recursive(n-1,k-1) + k*s_recursive(n-1,k);
}
```

Comment: Oh, just in case, these are for Stirling numbers of the second kind. If you want the first kind there's a signed recurrence such that `arr[j] -= (i+j+1)*arr[j-1]`. It also requires beginning the sequence with arr all zeros except the first element, `i=1` as it originally was, and the the returned value must be `(arr[maxj]<0) ? -arr[maxj] : arr[maxj];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the bug.
You already computed your dynamic array of Stirlings numbers for k=1 (S(n,1)=1 for all n).
You should start computing S(n,2) - that is:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= k; ++i) //i=2, not 1
  for(int j = 1; j <= maxj; ++j)
    arr[j] += i*arr[j-1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is just fine, except you seem to have made a simple indexing error. If you think about what indexes `i` and `j` represent, and what the inner loop transforms `arr[j]` to, you'll see it easy enough (I lie, it took me a good half hour to figure out what was what :)).

From what I can decode, `i` represents the value `k` during calculations, and `arr[j]` is transformed from `S(i+j, i-1)` to `S(i+1+j, i)`. The topmost for loop that initializes `arr` sets it up as `S(1+j, 1)`. According to these loops, the calculations look just fine. Except for one thing: The very first `i` loop assumes that `arr[j]` contains `S(0+j, 0)`, and so it is where your problem lies. If you change the starting value of `i` from `1` to `2`, all should be OK (you may need an if or two for edge cases). The initial `i=2` will transform `arr[j]` from `S(1+j, 1)` to `S(2+j, 2)`, and the rest of the transformations will be just fine.

Alternatively, you could have initialized `arr[j]` to `S(0+j, 0)` if it were defined, but unfortunately, Stirling's numbers are undefined at `k=0`.

EDIT: Apparently I was wrong in my last comment. If you initialize arr to {1, 0, 0, ...}, you can leave starting value of `i` as `1`. For this, you use the initial values `S(0, 0)=1`, and `S(n, 0)=0, n>0` instead.

Comment: Your answer provided me with a lot of info, but the accepted one was more on point. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: No worries, he made it there first in any case. :)

Comment: @vhallac You said  arr[j] is transformed from S(i+j, i-1) to S(i+1+j, i) but it should be transformed from S(i+j-1, i-1) to S(i+j, i)